# Can tcpdump filter by application layer protocol?

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, libpcap

I have not had much luck in finding a way for tcpdump to filter by the application layer protocol, like HTTP or FTP. It seems it can filter by at most transport layer protocols like TCP or UDP: https://linux.die.net/man/7/pcap-filter

Is it true tcpdump does not have the functionality to examine and identify application layer protocol headers, like Wireshark does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) use the pcap filters syntax and allows you to filter by port with:

```
tcp port 80
```

or

```
tcp port 21
```

If you want to filter by application layer protocol, you will have to use [TShark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html). With this tool you can use [capture filters](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters) with the same syntax as pcap filters but also [display filters](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters) which allow you to filter by application layer protocol with:

```
http
```

or

```
ftp
```